# Form without Model attached

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I would like build a custom login form for users who have an account on another website. I will check the credentials with an API and if they are correct I will create a User Entity and log the user in.

The issue if that I don't have/need any Model attached to my login form. 
Is there a way to build such a form and process it with validators etc.?

EDIT:
I have tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271051/6800816

but submitting the form simply reloads the page ... The action that handles the form on submitting is never being called

Answer (score 1):

You probably does not need to build up your own login-form as the login process in TYPO3 can handle foreign logins (SSO, LDap). you might have alook into the TER to find some extensions, which manage the connection of external login services. (Keywords: `SSO`, `oAuth`, `LDap`)

In Case you miss an option you still can [build your own authentification service](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Typo3ServicesReference/Authentication/Index.html) without the neccessarity of building your own form.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I would rather build a separate form because SSO user are managed differently. Do I have to use the authentication service to trigger a login after I validate the form ?

Comment: I think you can't avoid it. if you provide your own authentication service you can do any check. SSO is just one example how an authentication service can be realized: take a new extension (matching current versions of TYPO3) and have a look into the code.